# Given a string, how to determine if it's an IMDB id?

Tags: javascript, regex, coldfusion, imdb

For the regex experts out there, I need to determine whether a given string is a properly formatted [IMDB Id](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P345).

Need to do this in either ColdFusion or JavaScript. ColdFusion would look like: `REFind(regex, "tt32423")`, and JavaScript would look like `regex.test('tt32432')`, if we can get the value of `regex`.

Comment: Uh, from the _discussion_ tab https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property_talk:P345 `ev\d{7}/\d{4}(-\d)?|(ch|co|ev|nm|tt)\d{7}`

Comment: @RobG Good point, changed the wording there :-)

Comment: @sln Sure enough, there it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the discussion tab of the page you linked to, you can use this RegEx in JavaScript: `/ev\d{7}\/\d{4}(-\d)?|(ch|co|ev|nm|tt)\d{7}/`

example:

```
/ev\d{7}\/\d{4}(-\d)?|(ch|co|ev|nm|tt)\d{7}/.test("tt2964642")
```

Even though the ID you provided in your example fails this test, when entered  as a route parameter to http://imdb.com/title/tt32423 in my browser, i'm redirected to http://imdb.com/title/tt0032423. Given that, depending on how you'll use this, you could adjust the regex to included 1 to 7 digits instead

> {7} becomes {1,7}

Up to you.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `/^ev\d{7}\/\d{4}(-\d)?$|^(ch|co|ev|nm|tt)\d{7}$/` to make sure there are no extra characters?

Comment: Sure, you would absolutely want to be as restrictive as your dataset allows.